# Setting a range on a state value

Tags: reactjs

im trying to set a range on the year state , i've tried assiging an operator and if statement to the state something like: if year<2020 then year=2020

and it didnt work... this full code is down below.

```
function MonthlyCalendar() {
  const [year, setYear] = useState(2020);  
return(
  <div>
<div id="MainMonthlyTableContainer">
        <div id="YearSelectDiv">
          <span id="YearSelectDesign">
            <a
              href="#"
              className="DateButtons"
              onClick={() => setYear(year + 1)}
            >
              ❮
            </a>
            {year}
            <a
              href="#"
              className="DateButtons"
              onClick={() => setYear(year - 1)}
            >
              ❯
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>

)}
```

Comment: What's not working? (Also, using `<a>` elements with an `href` will try and navigate around your page, these should probably be buttons) Edit: Oh, you want a min/max date? You could look at Math.min and Math.max and compare your min/max dates with your new year + 1 value.

Comment: i think you are just missing two closing divs in the end , and it would help if you can share the error text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is to use [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to limit the new values you create.

e.g. `onClick={() => setYear(Math.min(year + 1, 2020))}`

Will give you the year + 1, up to a maximum of 2020.

You should also consider using buttons instead of `<a>`, as they are a better fit for what you are trying to do (Though you may want to change the styling a little)

Here's an example of your current code with these changes:

```
function MonthlyCalendar() {
  const [year, setYear] = useState(2020);
  const maxYear = 2020;
  const minYear = 1950;
  return(
    <div>
      <div id="MainMonthlyTableContainer">
        <div id="YearSelectDiv">
          <span id="YearSelectDesign">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="DateButtons"
              onClick={() => setYear(Math.min(year + 1, maxYear))}
            >❮</button>
            {year}
            <button
              type="button"
              className="DateButtons"
              onClick={() => setYear(Math.max(year - 1, minYear))}
            >❯</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(You do seem to have increase as the left arrow and decrease on the right, which I would personally expect to be the other way around, but I've left them as they were in the question)